# Relacionar dos campos a una misma llave primaria PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Así es como tengo el código `MySQL` de mis tablas.

## **tasks**:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks(
task_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
created_by INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
support_by INTEGER UNSIGNED,
customer_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
request_of VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
description TEXT NOT NULL,
status_task ENUM('PENDIENTE', 'EN PROCESO', 'COMPLETADA', 'CANCELADA') NOT NULL,
start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
finish_date DATETIME,
FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES technicians(technician_id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,

FOREIGN KEY (support_by) REFERENCES technicians(technician_id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,

FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

## **technicians:**

```
CREATE TABLE technicians(
technician_id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name_tech VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
username_tech VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
pass_tech VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
role ENUM('technician', 'administrator') NOT NULL
);
```

**Me muestra el siguiente error al querer insertarle datos:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`amber`.`tasks`, CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`support_by`) REFERENCES `technicians` (`technician_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\amber\db\import.php:107 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\amber\db\import.php(107): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\amber\db\import.php on line 107

### Importante:

Lo que quiero hacer es poder insertar el campo support_by como NULL pero no me lo permite, les dejo el código del insertar en el siguiente enlace: [import.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/744a3dd3c893307fa4c472c71e178ee9) y el archivo [tasks.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f85d3df0e776ba89b79c31764562d584) – Nilton Venegas hace 15 min

Comment: El error me parece bien claro. Estás tratando de agregar un nuevo registro en la tabla `tasks` con un valor `support_by` que no existe en tu tabla `technicians`. ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando se crea el registro, el campo support_by esta vacio, ese campo se llena cuando alguien edita el registro y se añade su codigo de empleado en ese campo (support_by). ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para insertar un registro en "tasks" sin llenar ese campo?

Comment: ¿Qué tal si incluyes el código que hace el insert? Pero te diré que si de verdad no le asignas un valor a `support_by`, entonces no recibirás ese error. El error lo recibes porque sí le estás asignando un valor inválido, que te hayas dado cuenta o no.

Comment: tenes que borrar la foreign key entonces

Comment: @Leonardo: No, eso no es cierto.

Comment: entonces que acepte null el campo

Comment: @Leonardo: La tabla/columna ya está definida de esa manera. El problema está con el insert, nada más.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es poder insertar el campo support_by como NULL pero no me lo permite, les dejo el código del insertar en el siguiente enlace: [import.php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/744a3dd3c893307fa4c472c71e178ee9/) y el archivo [tasks.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f85d3df0e776ba89b79c31764562d584)

Comment: *Lo que quiero hacer es poder insertar el campo support_by como NULL*... Vas a tener que revisar la lógica de tu diseño. Ese campo no podrá ser `NULL` si está relacionado con otro campo de otra tabla `technician_id` que es clave primaria. Un diseño pensado así viola la integridad referencial.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Claro que sí puede, y no viola ninguna integridad referencial. La integridad referencial está allí simplemente para validar cuando el valor no es null.

Comment: @Nilton: Por favor incluye la porción de código relevante directamente en tu pregunta.

Comment: @sstan *LA integridad referencial está allí simplemente para validar con el valor no es null.*  Que es precisamente lo que él quiere  hacer, asignar un valor `NULL` en la tabla padre, cuando en la tabla hija ese campo es clave primaria y por lo tanto no admitirá nulos. Un diseño así está destinado al fracaso por donde quiera que lo midas.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Tal vez hay una confusión. `support_by` está en la tabla hija, no padre. No hay ningún problema con que esta sea null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo que quiero hacer es poder insertar el campo `support_by` como `NULL` pero no me lo permite

Sí lo permite. Prueba, con un ejemplo simplificado, de que sí se puede asignar `NULL` en un caso como este: <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/IQRGW14121)</kbd>

El problema, sencillamente, es que el valor que le estás asignando no es `NULL`, aunque pienses que sí lo es.

Mirando tu código, veo que tu `INSERT` es el siguiente:

```sql
INSERT INTO tasks (task_id, created_by, support_by, customer_id, request_of,
                   description, status_task, start_date, finish_date)
           VALUES (:task_id, :created_by, :support_by, :customer_id, :request_of,
                   :description, :status_task, :start_date, :finish_date)
```

O sea que sí le estás asignando un valor a la columna `support_by`. Si este valor no es null (que obviamente es tu caso), entonces MySQL te va a tirar un error si este valor no existe en la tabla `technicians`.

Toma en cuenta que tratar de pasarle una cadena vacía, que bien pudiera ser lo que estás haciendo, no es lo mismo que asignarle un `NULL`. Dependiendo de la configuración de tu MySQL, si le tratas de asignar una cadena vacía, puede ser que te tire un error por no asignarle un valor numérico. Pero por veces, en vez de quejarse por eso, automáticamente convierte la cadena vacía a un `0`. Probablemente esto es lo que está pasando en tu caso. Nota, con la demostración siguiente, cómo esto puede suceder: <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/JEOHB39250)</kbd>

La solución es que de verdad le asignes un valor `NULL`, no solamente una cadena vacía. O, si sabes que nunca vas a querer asignarle un valor a esa columna durante el `INSERT`, porque la idea es que se la vas a agregar mas tarde con un `UPDATE`, entonces ni siquiera debería incluir esa columna en la sentencia `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO tasks (task_id, created_by, customer_id, request_of,
                   description, status_task, start_date, finish_date)
           VALUES (:task_id, :created_by, :customer_id, :request_of,
                   :description, :status_task, :start_date, :finish_date)
```

Comment: Si le estoy asignando NULL, checa el log de MySQL: `20 Query INSERT INTO tasks (task_id, created_by, support_by, customer_id, request_of, description, status_task, start_date, finish_date) VALUES ('1', '2', 'NULL', '7', 'Ellen Olvera', 'Sed ornare ex maximus varius finibus.', 'PENDIENTE', '2017-10-28 11:59:54', '')` le esta poniendo comillas simples al NULL, por eso toma ese valor como si fuera una cadena de texto por eso dice que el campo no existe y muestra ese error.

Comment: De todas maneras tu solución me parece buena.